# How to calculate the distance between object and camera, knowing the pixels occupied by the object in an image- segmentation

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

**By using the segmentation I am able to find the number of pixels occupied by an object in an image. Now I need to kind the distance by using the pixels occupied.**

- I have the original dimensions of the object (W x H)

Comment: you cannot derive the distance from a single image dimension.

Comment: Just as an idea, you might take a few images of the same object with the fixed zoom adjustment. Then you measure your distance to the object and calculate the ratio `# pixels / (W x H)` for every image. By doing this, you might catch a correlation between these two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we will assume that the lens focuses the image flat.

After segmenting the object out, you will have W2 x H2, the pixel dimensions of the object.

Compare the actual dimensions of the object W x H to your measured dimensions. Take

```
%Scale on width axis
W / W2 = s1
%Scale on height axis
H / H2 = s2
%Average both scales
s = (s1 + s2) / 2
```

`s` will be your scale measured in meters/pixel. Now examine the total dimensions of the image in pixels, ie `1000 x 1000` or similar. If `s=0.01` then your total dimensions would be calculated as

```
dim * s = L
1000 * 0.01 = 10 meters
```

Where 10 meters is the size of your frame.

Now you are stuck. If you only have the one image you will not be able to calculate the distance to the object. You need to know how wide the angle of the lens is. This can be taken from the camera specifications or can be derived. If you take one image, measure the distance to the object with a meterstick. Lets call this dimension `d`.

We will use some trigonometry to derive the angle of the aperture. For example let `d=20 meters`

```
arctan(L/2 / d) = theta
arctan(10/2 / 20) = 14 degrees
```

With theta derived, let's consider an example. You find `L = 10` and have observed `theta = 14`.

```
L/2 / tan(theta) = d
10/2 / tan(14) = 20 meters
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use the concept of camera calibration and the formula for perspective projection. This involves determining the camera's focal length, which can be obtained through calibration, and then using the formula:
distance = (object actual height*focal length)/object image height in pixels.